what is $\gamma'(t)$?
Here is the question I am trying to solve:
$(a)$ Given $A \in PSL(2, \mathbb R),$ show that its derivative $D_z A$ satisfies $$g_{Az} (D_z Av, D_z Aw) = g_z(v,w)$$ for all $z \in \mathbb H^2$ and $u,w \in T_z\mathbb H^2.$
Where $g$ is the Remanian metric defined by $ds^2_{x + iy}(v,w) = (1/y^2)(dx^2 + dy^2)$ where $x \in \mathbb R$ and $y \in (0, \infty).$
Knowing that $PSL(2, \mathbb R)$ acts on $\mathbb H^2$ by $$
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d
  \end{array} } \right].z = \frac{ az + b}{cz + d}
$$
One thing confuses me is the definition of the Riemannian what is the role of the point $(v,w)$ in it? I think in our case here $v = \gamma'(0),$ am I correct? And $D_z A(z)(v) = dA(z)/dz . \gamma'(0),$ where . means dot product, am I correct?  I got $D_zA(z) = 1/(cz + d)^2.$ but I am wondering what should I use for $\gamma'(t)$? What will be the parametrization? Or can I use $v$ directly? And if so, how?
Could anyone clarify these questions please?

@Lee, Yes, you're right. I typed too hastily. (Of course, you're right. I'll delete my comment.)

On the right hand side of your equation, you need to keep better track of the meaning of the expression $g_z(v,w)$. It represents an inner product:

$g_z$ is expressed as a matrix
$$g_z = \begin{pmatrix} E & F \\ F & G \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{y^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{y^2} \end{pmatrix}
$$
$v,w$ are just vectors, expressed as column matrices
$$v = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} \qquad w = \begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
And, finally,
$$g_z(v,w) = v^T \begin{pmatrix} E & F \\ F & G \end{pmatrix} w = \frac{v_1 w_1 + v_2 w_2}{y^2}
$$


The left hand side of your equation is more straightforward, although you do have to tread carefully back and forth between complex numbers and their representation as real vectors. This is necessitated by the mixture of real number notation and complex number notation in the problem; just keep your head on straight and remember that $z=x+iy$.
You already have a formula for $A(z)$, namely $A(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Now compute the complex derivative $D_zA = A'(z)$; the result is just a complex number. To compute $D_zA v$, you'll have to convert $v$ from a real vector to a complex number, then you have a complex number multiplied by a complex number, the product is a complex number, and you convert that back to a real vector. Similarly for $D_z Aw$.

what about $\gamma(t)$?

what are E,F and G?

There is no $\gamma(t)$ in this problem. In other problems, $\gamma(t)$ might represent a smooth path in $\mathbb H^2$ and $\gamma'(t) \in \mathbb R^2$ would be the velocity vector of that path at the point $\gamma(t) \in \mathbb H^2$.

Riemannian metrics on the plane (with $x,y$ coordinates) are traditionally written in the form $g_{(x,y)} = E(x,y) , dx^2 + 2F(x,y) dx , dy + G(x,y) , dy^2$, or in matrix form as $\begin{pmatrix} E(x,y) & F(x,y) \ F(x,y) & G(x,y) \end{pmatrix}$. So in this problem, $E(x,y) = \frac{1}{y^2}$, $F(x,y)=0$, $G(x,y)=\frac{1}{y^2}$.

but then what is the left hand side in this case? You computed the right hand side of what I want to compute.

I added some comments about the left hand side.
